# How to setup Subdomain directories with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

I have subdomain, got error 404 while clicking on links. I want to be able to click on each link without getting any error messages. How can I setup the .htaccess file? currently using codeIgniter.

Here's the situation 
Ex: 
mysubdomain.website.com -> mysubdomain.website.com/gallery1 = display error 404
mysubdomain.website.com -> mysubdomain.website.com/gallery2 = display error 404

NB: BTW I Don't want to redirect mysubdomain.website.com to website.com/mysubdomain/gallery1

Any helps migh appreciate
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My .htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|phpmyadmin|robots\.txt|ckeditor|css|js|favicon\.png|captcha|img|uploads)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Anything other than given values "images", "phpmyadmin" etc. will be looked up in config/routes.php

So:

```
 http://127.0.0.1/css/style.css
```

Will return file at www/css/style.css

```
 http://127.0.0.1/anything
```

will be taken as CodeIgniter link

Edit: Don't forget to update your config file with

```
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Your htaccess doesn't Work!! I always get error 404 Page Not Found. Btw, I didn't touch config['index_page'] = ''; Keep it blank as default... Does anyone have a better way to fix it?

Comment: Try changing <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> to <IfModule mod_rewrite.so>.